# Bind a click to a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have followed most of the beginners tutorials, but now I am trying to do a clean jquery plugin. My goal (right now) is to show an alert when a user click on a link (using a plugin).

my code to call the plugin is :

```
//custom.js
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $("a").click(function(event){
     alert("TEST1");
     myPlugin();
     event.preventDefault();
   });
 });
```

and my plugin code is :

```
//myPlugin.jquery.js
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    alert("TEST2");

  };
})( jQuery );
```

TEST1 is showed but not TEST2 !

What's wrong ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: That's really not how jQuery plugins work. They need to be called **on a jQuery object**, like this: `$('a').myPlugin();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `$.fn.myPlugin` that means you need to use `$(this).myPlugin()` to call the plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $("a").click(function(event){
    alert("TEST1");
    $(this).myPlugin();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nf5b/

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin extends the jQuery object, so to invoke it you need a jQuery object.  Change your call from `myPlugin();` to `$(this).myPlugin();`